# one element to change color while hovering another one

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I tried so far. As they are in different divs and in no parent, sibling or child relation with each other, by my understanding CSS is no valid option.

```
 <script>
var circleOne = document.querySelector('.first_circle');
var adressOne = document.querySelector('.first_adress');

if (circleOne.matches(':hover')) {
    adressOne.style.color='green'; 
} else {
    adressOne.style.color='black';
}

</script>
```

Comment: You need to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and events like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for this. (even if your if block works in theory, you would have to put it in some kind of loop; otherwise it'll only run once when the page loads, then never again. which is why event listeners exist)

Comment: As sidenote: You should avoid to use `.style` function in JS in 2021. The modern approach is to use `.classList` +
 `.add('class-name')` , `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` to apply changes through CSS.
 This causes far less issues incl. possible specificity weight issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`

```js
var circleOne = document.querySelector('.first_circle');
var adressOne = document.querySelector('.first_adress');

circleOne.onmouseenter = () => adressOne.style.color='green';
circleOne.onmouseleave = () => adressOne.style.color='black';
```

```html
<div class="first_circle">First Circle</div>
<div class="first_adress">First Address</div>
```

Comment: Please check for [dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+one+element+to+change+color+while+hovering+another+one+site%3Astackoverflow.com) before posting an answer. If you find a beginner's question with a simple answer and know the solution right away, the chances of it being a dupe are about 100%

Answer (score 0):

You should use mouseenter, mouseleave event listeners for this task

```js
const firstEl = document.getElementById('first');
const secondEl = document.getElementById('second');

firstEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => secondEl.style.background = 'black');
firstEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => secondEl.style.background = 'transparent');

secondEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => firstEl.style.background = 'blue');
secondEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => firstEl.style.background = 'transparent');
```

```css
#first, #second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: Please check for [dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+one+element+to+change+color+while+hovering+another+one+site%3Astackoverflow.com) before posting an answer. If you find a beginner's question with a simple answer and know the solution right away, the chances of it being a dupe are about 100%